# There should the foreign key exist in a one to zero or 1 relationship?

Tags: mysql, database

Given a 1:0/1 relationship between a Parent and Child, should the Parent have a nullable reference to the Child or should the Child have a reference to the Parent, and why?

(In case it isn't clear, I'm asking about general database design).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter much with 1:0/1, however it's always better to have no nulls in database if it's possible - so it's better when Child have a reference to the Parent. One reason is to save space on disk - keeping nulls in table takes space as well.